# append for first class no for all?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want use append for first `$class`, how is it?

```
var $class =  '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');

$(this).closest($class).find('.adda:first-child .mediumCell').append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>')
```

**EDIT:** this my full code:

```
$('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $class =  '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
                $(this).closest($class).prev().find('.adda .mediumCell').first().append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>')
                $(this).closest($class).remove();
            });
```

html:(i use of several html and several $class)

```
<div class="column find_input">
    <div class="add_units">
        <div class="mediumCell">
            <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="hello" class="numeric" style="width: 70px;">
        </div>
        <div class="column adda" style="margin: 5px 1145px 0 0; position: absolute; float: left;">
            <div class="mediumCell">
                <a href="" class="add_input">add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: append `.append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>')` for first child `$class`. ok?

Comment: a class, like: `.hello` -> `var $class =  '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');`

Comment: show youre html and where you wanna append please.

Comment: i putting full code, please see first my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to select the first element of a set of matched elements just use first().

```
$(yourselector).first().doStuff();
```

Doc is here: http://api.jquery.com/first/

The following should add the link to the first $class only:

```
$('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $class = '.' +  $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
    $($class).first().find('.adda .mediumCell').append('<a href="" class="add_input">add</a>')
    $(this).closest($class).remove();
});
```

Comment: this not work. i putting full code, please see first my post.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Are you sure you want to use .find("div") ? and not .children("div")?

Because, .find("div") will return all the div that are descendant of the find_input div.

Comment: `.append('<a href="" class="add_input"></a>')` for first selector in class var $class no for all $class.